# Compare date in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have js function

```
function getDriving() {
markers.length = 0;
var todayval = new Date();
var newtodaydata = new Date(todayval.toDateString());
console.log(newtodaydata);
var url = $('#map').data('request-url2');
$.getJSON(url,
    function (data) {
        $.each(data,
            function (i, item) {

                markers.push({
                    'location': new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude),
                    'map': map,
                    'weight': item.Speed,
                    'radius': 10,
                    'date': item.CurrentDateTime,
                    'imei': item.Imei
                });
            });
        var todaymarkersfiltered = markers.filter(function (marker) {
            var getDate = marker.date.match(/\d/g).join('');
            var markerDate = new Date(parseFloat(getDate));
            console.log(markerDate);
            return (markerDate === todayval);
        });

        var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(todaymarkersfiltered);
        console.log(pointArray);
        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray
        });
        heatmap.setMap(map);
    });
```

};

Here is what  i have for `var newtodaydata = new Date(todayval.toDateString());`

> Thu Jan 25 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)

And in `console.log(markerDate);` I have 2 markers with same data

But in  `todaymarkersfiltered` I have no markers.

Where is my problem?

Thank's for help.

Comment: You're comparing using `===` , the identity comparison. Since you're comparing two separate objects, they aren't identical. Try `==` instead for starters. However you'll probably want to use moment.js instead.

Comment: Your callback hell code seems ugly, switch to `async/await` ES2017

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, I rewrite condition `===` to `==`

And make it like this `markerDate.toDateString() == todayval.toDateString()`

I rewrite code like this

```
  function getDriving() {
    markers.length = 0;
    var todayval = new Date();


    var url = $('#map').data('request-url2');
    $.getJSON(url,
        function (data) {
            $.each(data,
                function (i, item) {

                    markers.push({
                        'location': new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude),
                        'map': map,
                        'weight': item.Speed,
                        'radius': 10,
                        'date': item.CurrentDateTime,
                        'imei': item.Imei
                    });
                });
            var todaymarkersfiltered = markers.filter(function (marker) {
                var getDate = marker.date.match(/\d/g).join('');
                var markerDate = new Date(parseFloat(getDate));

                return (markerDate.toDateString() == todayval.toDateString());
            });

            var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(todaymarkersfiltered);
            console.log(pointArray);
            heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: pointArray
            });
            heatmap.setMap(map);
        });
};
```

And now all okay

Comment: You should be specific on what was changed